# Realm DB - exception thrown for no apparent reason

Tags: c#, xamarin, realm

I have a refresh command in a Xamarin page, and for some reason, Realm throws a `RealmInvalidTransactionException` when it finishes. In their [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/3.0.0/api/reference/Realms.Exceptions.RealmInvalidTransactionException.html) they wrote:

> An exception, thrown when trying to write data to the Realm outside a Transaction or when trying to create a transaction on a Realm that is opened as read-only.

This is my refresh command:

```cs
ICommand refreshCommand = new Command(async () =>
{
    refreshView.IsRefreshing = true;

    // Refresh everything
    var w = summaryViewModel.Articles[0];
    WebArticlesListView.RefreshCommand.Execute(null);
    summaryViewModel.UpdateSummaryCommand.Execute(null);


    // wait for articles to finish loading to stop loading indicator
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            while (w == summaryViewModel.Articles[0]) ;
        }
        catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException e)
        {
            while (summaryViewModel.Articles.Count < 5) ;
        }                
    });
    refreshView.IsRefreshing = false;
});
```

While debugging, I noticed that the exception is only thrown right after the refresh command finishes (I went step by step with VS's debugger and it was thrown right after I pressed `F10` [step] on the last curly brackets). No object is trying to access the DB after it, and nothing happens from my code after the command finishes its job, so I don't understand why the exception would be thrown. Moreover, the stack trace of the exception is `[External Code]` based on the Call Stack column in VS's debugger.

*Edit: I'm using Xamarin for Android and iOS.*

Comment: Try to place an exception catchpoint and see the exact line that the exception is thrown. Can you also share more details of your stack trace and app output

Comment: @Saamer, I know for sure that the exception is thrown right after the command finishes, since I've used VS's debugger and right after I pressed `F10` when on the last curly brackets (last line of this code) the exception is thrown. As for the output, I don't have it since I'm trying to find ways around it  right now and get other exceptions, which make sense. In addition, from what I can remember, the stack trace was "External Code", so not even my application.

Comment: What platform are you running this on? Note that the two-way databinding only works on iOS and Android. On other platforms, if the UI tries to write to a RealmObject instance, you will need to have manually opened a transaction before that.